# pixel wise maths in hdf5 file in R

Tags: r, raster, hdf5, rhdf5

I have hdf5 raster file containing hyperspectral data.

in R programming language I did

```
f <- paste0(wd,"img1.h5")
View(h5ls(f,all=T))
```

output is of reflectance data is:

```
/SITE-NAME/Reflectance/Reflectance_Data
```

with dimension (3311,  678,  425) of (rows, columns, bands).

I need to do some calculations not as band maths but as spectral math i.e., pixel wise calculations.

Every spectrum (pixel) x is replaced by x<sub>bn</sub>, deﬁned as x divided by the length of its vector||x||.
[Equation for calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KAcR.png)

How it is to be done.

I have no idea how would I do that in R.. I able to do band calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding any complicating side issues (such as RAM overloading and performance related to different data storage models in the file and in R), the basic function to calculate x<sub>bn</sub> is relatively straightforward:

```
# x is a vector of spectral values for a single pixel
xbn <- function(x) {
  x / sqrt(sum(x^2))
}
```

This gives you the 425 `bn` values for every spectral band that makes up the pixel.

Applying this function over your entire image is equally straightforward:

```
# Load your data into R, calling it here img1

img1bn <- apply(img1, MARGIN = c(1, 2), xbn) |> aperm(c(2, 3, 1))
```

The `apply()` function runs a function (`xbn()` here) over one or more dimensions of an array, in this case the first two dimensions representing the column and rows of your data. `apply()` then takes the data in the remaining dimension(s) (your spectral data) and feeds that to the supplied function.

Somewhat annoyingly (but understandable from a performance perspective), the result has its dimensions swapped, with the dimension(s) over which the function is applied coming first and the margin dimensions following. That is fixed using the `aperm()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(f)
# or 
x <- sds(f)
```

And figure out how to subset the variable of interest. I cannot tell you how since I do not have the file.

After that you can do

```
bn <- app(x, \(i) i / sqrt(sum(i^2)))
```